# Make eclipse auto import other class

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to auto import a specific class instead the default one?

My eclipse is always auto importing class `IllegalArgumentException` from package
`org.jboss.weld.exceptions` instead of default Java package `java.lang`;

I want to force it to auto use `java.lang` package.

This is really annoying in Java-EE development since the class is not available on class path and the error just occurs at runtime when servers have started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore this by configuring a Type Filter in eclipse.

window -> preferences

in the dialog: 
java -> appearance -> Type Filters

button Add.

enter org.jboss.weld.exceptions.*

All classes from this package will be ignored for import or autocomplete.

[Eclipse reference of Type Filters](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fappearance%2Fref-preferences-type-filters.htm)

Answer (score 2):

At Preferences - Java - Appearance - Type Filters, you should add `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.*`

For example, this is what I configured in my eclipse, because it kept importing `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

open eclipse preferences (Windows/Preference) and edit **Java/Appearance/Type Filters** preferences by adding unwanted packages, they will no longer be proposed in quick fix popups.